# Can I access flags added by package @nuxtjs/device from the store?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to initialize a store state variable with a flag generated by `@nuxtjs/device`:

```
export const state = () => ({
  isMenuVisible: !$device.isMobile
});
```

This doesn't work though, I'm getting this error message:

> $device is not defined

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you missed 'this'

```
export const state = () => ({
  isMenuVisible: !this.$device.isMobile
});
```